# Avoid IFrame in ASP.NET MVC when nested form is needed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, razor

I have a product edit form and inside this form I have an area with another form that let's say allows you to enter a list of the customers to send a newsletter for this product.

Customers are not related to the product at all and has no database relation to a product. They are compliantly separate entities from product.

In this case I create an IFrame with a customer adding form and submit button that submits the form inside IFrame.

I didn't find any better way to implement the described scenario than using IFrame.
And yes, I have a requirement to have both forms on the same page, and newsletter form should be placed inside product editing form. Business need dictated by bosses.

I use ASP.NET MVC 3 / 4 and I can't use jQuery Ajax form because the native ASP.NET MVC binding and validation is needed.

I also tried to use one form for both product edit inputs and customer entries, having 2 buttons that submit to the same action, and checking what button was pressed - I got a problem of model validation. Because there is one ViewModel per page, and I can't validate only a part of the model (customer records) without validating the whole ProductEdit model (and I don't need to validate a product edit model while submitting customer records)

Is there any better way to avoid using IFrame in this situation?

Comment: you can still use the jQuery ajax form - it serializes as a standard form post by default, so the server won't notice the difference...

Comment: what about validation error messages that are automatically appended to the view when not using jQuery ajax form? I do use ajax, but I reload the div that contains the form, with partial view using jQuery ajax (not jQuery ajax form) and it allows me to get the error messages in place. I have also some Razor helpers that require the whole form HTML div to be processed on the server to add some autogenerated IDs.

Comment: Regarding the last scenario you describe (one form with two buttons), you could use ModelState.Clear() on properties that you don't want to validate.